# characterization of non-reflexive Kripke frames

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models

Can the class of non-reflexive (that is not being reflexive of course) be characterized with a set of modal formulae?

What about irreflexive (having only non-reflexive points)?

Comment: Are you familiar with p-morhisms?

Comment: @Vsotvep I am..

Comment: In that case, consider the frame with worlds $w_i$  for every natural number $i$, and as relation $w_i R w_j$ if and only if $j=i+1$. There is a p-morphism from this frame to the frame with a single reflexive world.

Comment: Thank you. it seems to solve both questions.